# How add embedded forum to existing JSP web application

Tags: java, jsp, forum

I am developing a web application using JSP. Now i want to add a forum to it. Please any one knows about embedded forums that can use with existing jsp web application.

Comment: You mean form or forum.

Comment: @GauravGupta - I want to add a forum to my web application.

Answer (score 0):

produce pages that display category, thread and posts. Landing on the category page display all categories. Click on one of them display all threads in that category. Click on one of them display all posts in that thread. Save theam all in a database linked by there numbers so each post belongs to a thread id. Each thread id belongs to a category.